# How to use FileSystemGlobbing.Matcher

Tags: c#, .net

How to use the `Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.Matcher` class. I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.filesystemglobbing.matcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0), but I still don't understand it.

I expect to be able to exclude the specified folder(use glob), but the code does not work:

```cs
var matcher = new Matcher();
matcher.AddExclude("foo/*.txt");
matcher.Match(new[] { "foo/a.txt", "foo/b.md", "bar/a.txt" }); // HasMatches: false
```

Expected:

```
foo/b.md
bar/a.txt
```

Actual:

```
// nothing
```

Comment: For those who tried to use `FileSystemGlobbing` and had the same problem as me: Apparently, the matcher doesn't support at all absolute paths or drive letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify what to include:

```
var matcher = new Matcher();
matcher.AddInclude("**"); // <-- this line is added
matcher.AddExclude("foo/*.txt");
matcher.Match(new[] { "foo/a.txt", "foo/b.md", "bar/a.txt" });
```

Answer (score 3):

There is not too much info about this class out there.

So, just in case somebody needs the same thing as I did, here's how I found all `config.json` files in all of my subdirectories excluding `node_modules` folder (because otherwise it takes too long):

```
var configPaths = new Matcher()
  .AddInclude("**/config.json")
  .AddExclude("**/node_modules/")
  .Execute(new DirectoryInfoWrapper(new DirectoryInfo(rootDir)))
  .Files
  .Select(x => x.Path)
  .ToArray();
```